# React input and state cannot override

Tags: javascript, reactjs

started learning react. I've been sitting on this problem for an hour and I have no idea why this is not working. Looking everywhere, but without any results. Am I dumb or what?

I cannot write in input field or when I can (if I fix it) then my state doesn't change. Maybe someone knows why is that a problem?

```
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: "test"
    }
  }

  textChangedHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState = ({
      text: event.target.value
    });
  } 

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>{this.state.text}</p>
        <input 
          type="text"
          onChange={this.textChangedHandler}
          value={this.state.text}> 
        </input>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: try this one in constructor `this. textChangedHandler = this. textChangedHandler.bind(this);`

Comment: thank you, tried it but still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see your `textChangedHandler`

```js
textChangedHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState = ({
      text: event.target.value
    });
  }
```

In this, 
you need to set state like this.

```js
this.setState({
  text: event.target.value
})
```

`this.setState` is a  method. You should need to reassign it.

Comment: Oh my code. Alright, i will understand this for the rest of my life...

Comment:  Yeah, it happens.

Answer (score 1):

```
textChangedHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        text: event.target.value
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <p>{this.state.text}</p>
            <input
                type="text"
                onChange={this.textChangedHandler}
                value={this.state.text}>
            </input>
        </div>
    );
}
```

try this.

Comment: Wait. what did you change. That's identical code, but it works? Can you explain it to me?

Comment: @PovilasDirse please do upvote if its working & cosider as marked .

Comment: `onChange={() => this.textChangedHandler()}` unnecessary, you create new function every render

Comment: if you use arrow function than you don't have to bind this function in your constructor.

Comment: @NikitaMadeev how ?

Comment: @VyasArpit You add new arrow function `onChange={() => this.textChangedHandler()}` but `textChangedHandler` already arrow function

Comment: @NikitaMadeev yeah it's every time create new function . Thanks !!

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```js
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: "test"
    }
    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.textChangedHandler = this.textChangedHandler.bind(this)
  }

  textChangedHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      text: event.target.value
    });
  } 

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>{this.state.text}</p>
        <input 
          type="text"
          onChange={this.textChangedHandler}
          value={this.state.text}> 
        </input>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

More information: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html